# Creating a Dialogue Path in DialogFlow After the User Signs In. Is that possible?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

If you create a dialogue path contingent on your user being logged in using Google Sign in. Does that mean all that path has to be done through ActionsOnGoogle Firebase Functions server side or can you do it in Dialogflow?

Answer (score 4):

You will probably need to add some custom logic in your webhook to do sign-in. Once that happens, you can set a [context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) for being signed-in. That way, in Dialogflow's UI you can create intents that only trigger with certain input contexts. This would allow you to use Dialogflow once the user is signed in.

However, the Dialogflow will not be able to do any advanced functionality to get information about the user such as querying a database or reading the user's profile. Those would still need to be done through a webhook.

Comment: Like the lovely workaround for contexts but you are right of course that I use Sign In to CRUD data using Firestore.

But love the idea and thanks for responding. If I had a unique conversation that didn't need data or returning their name or any other profile details then that would be a solutions.

If I am wrong, then please correct me BTW and again thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to store session data, as well as in a context, but using a context would be the best way to handle dialog paths in differente scenarios.

Comment: I'll play around with it at the weekend and see the cost/benefit. I think it's definitely something I need to investigate and see if it works as a solution. Still seeing some conflicts in the developing process but I might be wrong. Nothing better than getting your hands dirty to find out. Thanks again